# What is meant by a source-free conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, maxwell-equations, conductors

I have recently worked with a source-free conducting slab filled with free space and with an electric field inside, and I have determined the corresponding magnetic field from MW's eq's. Next, I wanted to determine the supplied complex power, wherein the magnetic and electric current density appear. What confuses me is that we work with a 'source-free' conducting slab while a conductor must contain free electrons in order to allow the flow of charge. Interpreting the source as some impressed current, it makes sense that it is separated from free charges and describe something completely different, but what exactly is this 'source' and why does it appear in the equation of supplied complex power (I guess that the impressed source current is just a result of this supplied complex power)?